# How do I know if I've finished everything and am ready for the trial?

Tags: paradise-killer

Is there any indication of when you've done everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could tell, no, there's not.  However, by the end of the game:

- The *"notes"* tab was empty
- Case files --> "unsorted evidence" was empty
- Holding 'ctrl' showed no more characters with red-exclamation points
- The only heart left when using the 'meditation' ability was the gun near Judge

However even then there are things that I nearly missed.  For example,

> Both the skid marks on the grate at the bottom of the rappel, and Lydia's knife on the beach below that.